# Android java, how to use an objects public method from a new helper class

Tags: java, android

Sorry for the jumbled name.

I have a class called ChatService which has public methods.

I then have a BaseActivity that has at the top

```
protected ChatService mChatService;
```

Then I have a class that extends BaseActivity and in that class I use the public methods of ChatService and it is working fine.

Now I want to move those methods into a new helper class.  The helper class has a public method which takes BaseActivity as an argument and is trying to use those public methods from ChatService however it can't find ChatService, how do I solve this problem, Thanks?

Comment: You can move the helper class in the same package as the `BaseActivity` class or declare `ChatService mChatService` as `public`. [More details here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got help from someone outside of the site, the solution is simply pass mChatservice as an argument to the last class